# merge two array if both token value is same

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have two arrays

1.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [token] => 5217158
            [time] => 234034
            [ltp] => 153.80
            [ltq] => 2
            [total_value] => 129688
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [token] => 5217158
            [time] => 234035
            [ltp] => 153.80
            [ltq] => 11
            [total_value] => 129699
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [token] => 5216450
            [time] => 234035
            [ltp] => 451.25
            [ltq] => 1
            [total_value] => 9947
        )
)
```

and 2.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [token] => 5216450
            [asd] => 4409
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [token] => 5217158
            [asd] => 29950
        )

)
```

I want to make array final

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [token] => 5217158
            [time] => 234034
            [ltp] => 153.80
            [ltq] => 2
            [total_value] => 129688
            ['asdf']=> 29950
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [token] => 5217158
            [time] => 234035
            [ltp] => 153.80
            [ltq] => 11
            [total_value] => 129699
            ['asdf']=> 29950
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [token] => 5216450
            [time] => 234035
            [ltp] => 451.25
            [ltq] => 1
            [total_value] => 9947
            ['asdf']=> 4409

        )
)
```

if token is same.

Comment: Please, correct your question. It is unreadable

Comment: please show us what you have tried to solve the issue, what doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($arrayOne as &$array1) {
    foreach ($arrayTwo as $array2) {
        if ($array1['token'] == $array2['token']) {
            $array1 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
        }
    }
}
```

It can be improved if you elaborate more.